# How to change containing folder name for a project in VS 2010 template

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have created a multi-project template in VS 2010 and the folder structure created is:

**Service1**

MyService.Service1.CommunicationLayer

-->MyService.Service1.CommunicationLayer.csproj

MyService.Service1.DataAccessLayer

-->MyService.Service1.DataAccessLayer.csproj

MyService.Service1.ServiceLayer

-->MyService.Service1.ServiceLayer.csproj

But I need the structure as follows:
**Service1**

Communication

-->MyService.Service1.CommunicationLayer.csproj

DataAccess

-->MyService.Service1.DataAccessLayer.csproj

Services

-->MyService.Service1.ServiceLayer.csproj

Also, I need my SolutionFolder name to be set to **Service1** which will be the name of project user provides.

Here is the .vstemplate file I am using:

```
`<!--Outer .vstemplate file -->
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>DataAccessService</Name>
    <Description>Data Access Service Template</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <ProvideDefaultName >true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <DefaultName>DALService</DefaultName>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyService.$safeprojectname$.CommunicationLayer">Communication\Communication.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyService.$safeprojectname$.DataAccessLayer">DataAccess\DataAccess.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyService.$safeprojectname$.ServiceLayer">Services\Services.vstemplate</ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So here is the solution I found:

I used TemplateWizard to customize my folder structure.

1. Create the projects with default project name and containing folder.
2. Create SolutionFolder using TemplateWizard.
3. Remove projects from Solution.
4. Rename the containing folder.
5. Add the project to SolutionFolder which I created in Step 2.

Hope this helps someone with similar issue.

Comment: Wow, that is not a very satisfying solution. :P

Comment: hi, can you pls give me more details about the steps? thanks!

Comment: When you say "using TemplateWizard", do you mean a custom IWizard implementation? Can you be more specific about what that code is? Thanks