# SolutionFolder name change based on the project name in multiproject template

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, vsix

My multiproject vstemplate looks as below

```
<TemplateContent>   
    <ProjectCollection>
<SolutionFolder Name="samplefolder">
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.projectone">            
                sample.projectone\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.projecttwo">
                sample.projecttwo\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink> 
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.projectthree">
                sample.projectthree\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
</SolutionFolder>
    </ProjectCollection> 
</TemplateContent>
```

Problem is I need to have the solutonfolder name to be same as the the projectname entered by user.
If I give $safeprojectname$' in the place of "samplefolder" the solution folder name is not being replaced.

Comment: When $safeprojectname$ is used as Name of SolutionFolder, it ends up literally as $safeprojectname$. :(

Comment: This should get fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer was not the perfect one as it doesn't work when the project is created under nested folders.

This is solved by giving a guid as solution folder name in the multiproject template and then looping through the projects in the solution to find the guid and rename the solution folder with the project name.

Posted the code [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88ba297b-5d88-42a3-98a7-9f784d842b5e/solution-folder-in-multiproject-template?forum=vsx#b39f697f-5589-481f-80a3-65e65521e988)

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution based on this post

[How to change containing folder name for a project in VS 2010 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985095/how-to-change-containing-folder-name-for-a-project-in-vs-2010-template)

by handling it in wizard.
Created solution folder, removed the projects from solution and added to the solution folder.

Comment: hi, can you pls give me more details about the steps? thanks!